# Need to print multiples of 2 and 3 with three different procedures.

Tags: vb.net

OK so I need some help with my vb.net class.
The question is:

*Write three programs to print the multiples of 2 and 3 with three different procedures. Call those procedures with the help of delegates in one program, events in a second, and threads in a third.*

My problem is not calling the functions, I can figure that out. The problem is how do I get the program to print out multiples? I think I might have to use the `mod` function but I am not sure; and maybe a loop so I can add a number to the variable multiple times, so then I can test to see if it has any remainders other than 0 since you find a multiple if it goes in evenly and has no remainders.

Comment: Instead of looping through all integers from 1 to x and checking if each is a multiple of y, why not loop though all integers from 1 to x and multiply the loop variable by y to *create* the multiples.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of homework to me. Stackoverflow is not a code request site. Try writing the code and post it here if you are having issues.

Comment: You need to include what you've tried so far. If you can't even get started with the three procedures, either you haven't been paying attention in class or your instructor has done a poor job and you need to ask them (or the teaching assistant) for help. You pay tuition for the education, and they need to earn their share of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers from 1 to 100 that are multiples of 2 and also multiples of 3:

```
For X as Integer = 0 to 100
    If X mod 2 = 0 And X Mod 3 = 0 Then Debug.Print X
Next
```